# jQuery Append ... Maybe

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK So I wrote the front end code for a page that uses Bootstrap and some custom bootstrap for row with 5 even columns.

But now the backend developers area asking that it changes so that you can put it into a loop, totally makes sense from there perspective.

So i have this HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid-5">
  <div class="span2">1</div>
  <div class="span2">2</div>
  <div class="span2">3</div>
  <div class="span2">4</div>
  <div class="span2">5</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid-5">  
  <div class="span2">6</div>
  <div class="span2">7</div>
  <div class="span2">8</div>
  <div class="span2">9</div>
  <div class="span2">10</div>
</div>
```

but i need to add the...

```
</div>
<div class="row-fluid-5">
```

from jQuery now (unless there is an even better way to do this).

So i know have the HTML looking like this

```
<div class="row-fluid-5">
  <div class="span2">1</div>
  <div class="span2">2</div>
  <div class="span2">3</div>
  <div class="span2">4</div>
  <div class="span2">5</div>
  <div class="span2">6</div>
  <div class="span2">7</div>
  <div class="span2">8</div>
  <div class="span2">9</div>
  <div class="span2">10</div>
</div>
```

And i want to use jQuery append to add the closing div and reopen the div with class="row-fluid-5"

I have tried using 2 different approches with jQuery but neither are giving the result that i want.

```
$(".span2:nth-child(4)").append('</div><div class="row-fluid-5"><div class="span2">');
```

as well as this

```
$(".span2").eq(4).append('</div><div class="row-fluid-5"><div class="span2">');
```

I have a fiddle for this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M32Ud/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could just rebuild the html structure with jQuery.
It will look cleaner and work dynamically for other cases?

Comment: So it isnt as easy as replacing the 6th <div class="span2"> with </div><div class="row-fluid-5"><div class="span2">

Comment: "</div><div><div>" gets converted to "<div><div></div></div>" jquery works with element nodes, not partial html strings.

Comment: Don't do this on the frontend, do this on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDDFX/) with the code being inserted right where needed.
All I had to do was surround your function with `$(function() { })` so that it'd be executed at page load. I also included jQuery, that wasn't being loaded.

Comment: Exactly what i needed! And sorry about not including jQuery totally missed that. appreciate the help! Cheers!

Comment: But that doesn't produce the result you wanted at all?

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUZ3x/1/) and let me know if that's what you wanted.

```
$(".span2").each(function() {
    var current = $(this);
    if($(this).index() == 4) {
        current.parent().after('<div class="row-fluid-5"></div>');
    } else if($(this).index() > 4) {
        $(".row-fluid-5:nth-child(2)").append($(this).clone());
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Always post code in the answer itself. Your answer should hold future meaning even when external links rot.

Comment: `current.append('</div><div class="row-fluid-5"><div class="span2">');` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a function that recreates the DOM just like you want, just pass the index number you want to split.

```
splitRowAt(5);

function splitRowAt(value){

  $('.row-fluid-5').after('<div class="row-fluid-5 first"></div>');
  $('.first').after('<div class="row-fluid-5 second"></div>');
  $( ".span2" ).each(function( index ) {
    if(index >= value)
      $('.second').append($(this));
    else
      $('.first').append($(this));
  });
  $('.row-fluid-5').first().remove();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting way to do this but when i apply it, i get 3 row-fluid-5 

I get second then first then another second

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed the order of the divs.
Corrected the code above, should be working correctly now.